# How to use replace function in Oracle to remove a string?

Tags: oracle, replace

In my table, I have data like PAT5DSA-(ALRP), LAR6DAOP-(RAH) etc..But I want to remove the strings like  -(xxxx) or -(xxx) which can be any alphabets inside braces. Tried using the below:

```
select replace(:code,'-(Aa-Zz)',null) from employee;
```

But this didn't work..Can anyone please help?

Comment: Not sure where you got that syntax from (it resembles regular expressions but it isn't). [`REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) does not support anything as fancy.

Answer (score 2):

We can do a regex replacement using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('PAT5DSA-(ALRP)', '-\(.*?\)', '')
FROM dual;

PAT5DSA
```

Answer (score 1):

The plain `replace()` doesn't understand patterns. You could use [a regular expression replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html), e.g.:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with cte (code) as (
  select 'PAT5DSA-(ALRP)' from dual
  union all
  select 'LAR6DAOP-(RAH)' from dual
)
select code, regexp_replace(code, '-\(.*?\)$') as result
from cte;

CODE           RESULT        
-------------- --------------
PAT5DSA-(ALRP) PAT5DSA       
LAR6DAOP-(RAH) LAR6DAOP
```

This will remove anything inside a pair of parentheses which is preceded by a dash, at the end of the original string. If the parentheses to be removed could be anywhere in the string then remove the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR`:

```
WITH cteVals AS (SELECT 'PAT5DSA-(ALRP)' AS COL_VAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'LAR6DAOP-(RAH)' AS COL_VAL FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUBSTR(COL_VAL, 1, INSTR(COL_VAL, '-')-1)
  FROM cteVals;
```

Best of luck.